# How to add data to Drupal.settings without drupal_add_js

Tags: 7, javascript

Is there any way to add some variables to `Drupal.settings` without `drupal_add_js` (with `setting` argument).

I'm creating a site that has a custom ctools popup style but I'm not feeling good with `drupal_add_js`. How can I add this JavaScript snippet to the page using the theme's `.info` page ? I'm not sure how can I merge my custom variables (literally, they are just static) to Drupal.settings so ctools module can pick them up as it was added via regular `drupal_add_js` call.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No there's no way to do that, you need to use `drupal_add_js` or an `#attached` property on a render array

Comment: Ohh.. I really wish Drupal has a little **more** magic to do that. Anyway, thank you very much for your help Clive.

Comment: No worries, I haven't put it in as an answer 'cos I'm hoping someone will know some sort of dark magic to prove me wrong :)

Comment: With using [JS injector](https://drupal.org/project/js_injector) you can add js code directly on the UI, and it provides conditionnals conditions (match pages urls)

Comment: @pico34 Can you use JS injector to manipulate `Drupal.settings`? That would be pretty cool

Comment: this is definitely not the magical module

Comment: Thanks @pico34 - actually my intention is to save some drupal_add_js calls and add those stuff to a static file for caching purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am missing a point to the question, but you should be able to do

```
scripts[] = path/to/your/script.js
```

in the .info file of your theme.  And within the script file something like

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    Drupal.settings.yoursetting = {};
    Drupal.settings.yoursetting.property = some_value;
});
})(jQuery);
```

or use the [Drupal.behaviors](https://drupal.org/node/756722) convention.

Comment: YOU ARE GENIUS WAYNE! This worked perfectly. Thank you very very much.